# do we have option to create Field mapping with choices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

can we define multiple choices for a Field when we define a document in Elasticsearch?
I want to create a field for status in my Index with choices.

eg. We define choices for our db tables/models in traditional DB.  Is their any similar approach available here?

status_choices = [
('NW','New'),
('IP', 'In-progress'),
('OH','On-hold'),
('CD','Closed')
]

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly via mappings (or templates), no

the approach Elasticsearch takes is that this is done by the ingestion process. you could do that with an ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch however